# EntityManager NULL con @PersistenceContext y con EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, red-hat, jboss-eap

Estoy creando un proyecto con las siguientes caracteristicas: Proyecto maven tipo war con ***jdk 1.8***, servidor de aplicaciones ***RedHatJboss EAP 7.1, DB Oracle 12c.***

Como podran ver en el archivo pom, estoy usando los repositorios en linea de Red-hat para la version de jboss eap 7.1.

El problema que tengo es que al momento de crear o injectar el EntityManager este siempre es `null`, y almomento de usarlo (ej: `em.persit(entidad)`) arroja una `NullPointerException` exactamente en la línea donde se usa.

**Archivo pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppServices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AppServices</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.1.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jboss.bom>7.1.5.GA</version.jboss.bom>
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>3.0.0-M3</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>3.2.3</version.war.plugin>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-legacy-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}-redhat-00002</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb3</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
    </profiles>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-eap-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss EAP Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-eap-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss EAP Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**Archivo Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AppServicesDS</jta-data-source>
      <class>co.com.company.appservices.persistencia.entidades.comun.UnaEntidad</class>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**La entidad**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NOMBRE_TABLA")
public class NombreTabla implements IEntidad<Integer>, Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idNombreTabla")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

//Constructor y metodos de acceso
}
```

**Interface repositorio**

```
public interface IRepositorio<K, E extends IEntidad<?>> extends Serializable {
    E buscarPorId(K id);
    void crear(E entidad);
    void eliminar(E entidad);
    E salvarOActualizar(E entidad);
}
```

**Clase abstracta repositorio**

```
public abstract class Repositorio<K, E extends IEntidad<?>> implements IRepositorio<K,E>{
    private Class<E> entidad;

    public Repositorio(Class<E> entidad) {
        this.entidad = entidad;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    @Override
    public void crear(E entidad) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entidad); //Aca se genera la excepcion
    }
}
```

**Implementacion repositorio**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class NombreTablaRepositorio extends Repositorio<Integer, NombreTabla>{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    public NombreTablaRepositorio() {
        super(NombreTabla.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.em;
    }
}
```

El error completo es:

> 01:12:01,283 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to
>   /AppServices/rest/administracion/nombres-tablas:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:422)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>         at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
>         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>         at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
>         at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at co.com.company.appservices.persistencia.repositorio.Repositorio.crear(Repositorio.java:28)
>         at co.com.company.appservices.negocio.administracion.impl.AdministracionTabla.crearNombreTabla(AdministracionTabla.java:29)
>         at co.com.company.appservices.rest.administracion.facade.TablaService.crearNombreTabla(TablaService.java:38)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
>         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
>         ... 44 more

Agradezco de su colaboración.

Comment: Ya lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: Raul le comento, si señor, y publico respuesta

Answer (score 1):

después de mucho leer, la solución no fue más que un manejo de dependencias e injección.

En el archivo `pom.xml` se adiciono la siguiente dependencia

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

En el archivo `persistence.xml` se cambiaron las versiones, esto de acuerdo a la guia de desarrollo de RedHat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasources/AppServicesDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Se adiciono una clase de recursos `Recursos.java` que produce el recurso del EntityManager

```
public class Resources {
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

La implementación del repositorio se transformo en un Session Bean sin estado y se inyecto el EntityManager

```
@Stateless
public class NombreTablaRepositorio extends Repositorio<Integer, NombreTabla>{

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;
//todo lo demas igual
```

Se creo una interface y una implementación que me ayudan de proxy para el uso de los repositorios, la interface es normal no tiene nada de especial. En cuanto a la implementación de la interface debe llevar la anotación `@ApplicationScoped` a nivel de clase y se inyecta el repositorio como un ejb

```
@EJB
private NombreClaseRepositorio nombreClaseRepositorio;
```

Y para usar el proxy lo inyectamos

```
@Inject
private IProxy proxy;
```

Los proxys los uso desde una clase de Recurso Web por lo cual la clase esta anotada con `@RequestScoped`

Y como nota final, si hacen su proyecto desde un arquetipo maven, borren todos los archivos que configuren datasources a bases de datos de ejemplo o reemplacelos con información de sus bases de datos, esto por que pueden intentar cargarse y pueden producir errores al desplegar la aplicación.