# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException con Hibernate 5, Glassfish 4, Maven, JTA, intentando hacer deploy a EJB

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, glassfish, ejb

gente. Estoy intentando hacer un deploy de un jar EJB usando java 1.8, maven y hibernate en un servidor Glassfish 4.1.

Este son las dependencias de mi pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Este es mi persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0"> 
    <persistence-unit name="PsePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/PseMySql</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <!-- GLASSFISH SPECIFIC: The following property is necessary for
            deployment within Glassfish.  Note that each application
            server vendor has its own unique value. -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Cuando intento hacer deploy, esta es parte de la traza de error:

```
[2019-08-25T15:11:51.438-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1566756711438] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while preparing the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:865)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)

etc, etc
```

Lo extraño es que con EclipseLink no sucede, pero cuando intento implementar Hibernate, rompe. Ya he probado agregando y quitando dependencias en el pom, agregando propiedades a la unidad de persistencia, y elr esultado es el mismo. Pareciera que se están omitiendo las librerías de hibernate, sin embargo, puedo verlas en las dependencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda de alguien que le haya sucedido lo mismo y haya podido resolver. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tuve un problema similar, revisa este hilo, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286456/entitymanager-null-con-persistencecontext-y-con-entitymanagerfactory/288147#288147

Comment: Gracias @isaac. En principio, tenía un error similar (NullPointerException). Después de intentar varias cosas, entre mis pruebas, decidí deployar aparte el EJB para ir separando errores. Y fue cuando vino el ClassNotFoundException. Acabo de hacer unos cambios y ya logré solventar, voy a actualizar el post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, logré resolverlo de la siguiente manera, tal como se indica [aquí:](https://coderwall.com/p/e5fxrw/use-hibernate-4-3-x-with-jta-on-glassfish-4)

1. Descargué los jar de la versión que estoy usando de Hibernate de [aquí](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/)
2. Copié los jars requeridos (carpeta required) en {Glassfish4 direcory}/glassfish/lib.
3. Copié jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final en {Glassfish4 direcory}/glassfish/lib/endorsed
4. Cambié la cabecera del persistence.xml, quedando así:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"> 
    <persistence-unit name="PsePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/PseMySql</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <!-- GLASSFISH SPECIFIC: The following property is necessary for
            deployment within Glassfish.  Note that each application
            server vendor has its own unique value. -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Ya pude hacer el deploy, si surge alguna novedad, actualizaré el post. Saludos.